# How To Delete Uploaded File On Local Host Along With User Account In Php

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

This is register page php code on which when user register then he has to upload file in txt || doc format.Now i want that whenever a user delete his account on delete.php by click on delete button so his uploaded file which uploded on "document folder in my localhost wamp www/govt/document" also should delete along with user account but right now only account is deleting and files are there,i want to delete those files which uploaded by that particular user who is logged in.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $day = $_POST['dob'];
    $month=$_POST['dob2'];
    $year = $_POST['dob3'];
    if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    }
    if(isset($_FILES['upload'])){
    $filename = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    $filetmp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
    $fileError= $_FILES['upload']['error'];
    $filesize= $_FILES['upload']['size'];
    }
$max=1000000;
if(!empty($name) && !empty($password) && !empty($day) && !empty($month) && !empty($year) && isset($gender)){
if(!empty($password)){
$password=sha1($password);
if(!empty($name)){
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM govtup WHERE name='$name'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($count==1) {
echo "This name is already registered please choose another username";
}else{
if($fileError==0){
if($filesize<=$max){
if (($filetype=="text/plain") || ($filetype=="application/msword")){
move_uploaded_file($filetmp, "document/".rand(100,9999999).time()."$filename");
$query2=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO govtup(name,password,day,month,year,gender) VALUES ('$name','$password','$day','$month','$year','$gender')");
if($query2){
unset($name);
header("Location: login.php");
echo "Successfully registered";
}else{
echo "not registered";
}
}else{
echo "only txt and doc file allowed";
}
}else{
echo "The file is too big please choose filesize less than 1mb";
}
}else{
echo "please choose a txt or doc file to upload";
}
}
}
}
}else{
echo "Please fill all the field";
}
}

?>
```

**Delete.php Code**
This is delete.php code which is deleting user account detail from mysql phpmyadmin here i want that when user click on delete account button then files which were uploaded by the user who is logged in right now should be delete along with user details.

```
<?php 

session_start();
require_once("inc/connection.php");
if(empty($_SESSION['usersession'])){
header("Location: login.php");
}
if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>REGISTER HERE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['usersession']['id']);
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM govtup WHERE id='$id'");
    if($query){
        header("Location: login.php");
    }else{
        echo "Unable to proccess your request";
    }
    $_SESSION['msg']="Your Account Has  Been Deleted";
    unset($_SESSION['usersession']);
}

?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" id="form">
<label class="lb">USERNAME</label><p>
<input type="text" name="name" class="int"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['name'];?>" readonly/><p>

<label class="lb">D.O.B</label><p>
<input type="text" name="dob" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['day']."-". $_SESSION['usersession']['month']."-".$_SESSION['usersession']['year']; ?>" readonly/>

<P>
<label class="lb">GENDER</label><p>
<input type="text" name="gender" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['gender'];?>" readonly/>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="delete" id="dbtn" value="delete account">
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dbtn").click(function(e){
            if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete your account")){
                e.preventDefault();
                return false
            }
            return true;

        })

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked for php unlink( ) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a **new column in DB** that will **store** the **file name**. Here i am **modifying** your **insert query**.

```
$query2=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO govtup(name,password,day,month,year,gender,file) VALUES ('$name','$password','$day','$month','$year','$gender','$filename')");
```

**Delete Part**

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['usersession']['id']);

    $select = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT file FROM govtup WHERE id='$id'")); //Fetch the file which is associated with this account

    unlink('YourFolderPath/'.$select['file']); //Deleting the file

    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM govtup WHERE id='$id'");
    if($query){
        header("Location: login.php");
    }else{
        echo "Unable to proccess your request";
    }
    $_SESSION['msg']="Your Account Has  Been Deleted";
    unset($_SESSION['usersession']);
}
```

Comment: i am creating a column in database for filename but what' type' should i choose for this ,if varchar  then what should be it's length because i am giving it a random number then timestamp then filename so it would be too long if 1000s of user register on my fom.

Comment: problem is solved but now another problem i got when i am editing it and uploading another file with different name that new file replacing the previous file which is ok but when i delete the account then it's only deleting one file which replaced the previous file but keeping the replaced file, i want to delete the all files which uploaded by user on time of register or after editing.

Comment: hey man problem not solved because it's only deleting the file from database not from the "folder"

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken, you are not storing the information, which file(s) belong(s) to the respective users anywhere.
If you stored the file name along with the user, you could retrieve the file name and `unlink` it.

Answer (score 0):

create folder with unique id.And assign it to the user.
if user delete his account delete associated folder with this .

```
rmdir($dirname)
```

Comment: can you tell me where should i use this code in my php code

Answer (score 0):

For your Deleting problem first of all check what your $select your return and also check your path of image by echo it. The file name in DB and in Folder should be same.

And for update problem first you will check if user change the image if he do then fetch the file name for that user from DB and unlink it in same way. And if user have not change the image then you need not to unlink that image and also not update DB column